# Освобождение памяти после sql запроса [PHP] [MYSQLI]

Tags: php, mysqli

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой связной с освобождением памяти на запрос. Текший код выглядят перемерено так:

```
  $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table`")->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

только сегодня исполняя SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; понял что так нельзя и нужно делать примерно так:

```
$result =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->free(); // Освобождает память от результата запроса
```

Если не проделывать эти действия очень часто в консоли появляется `Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=19797` или же в противном случае `MySQL server has gone away`

Возможно ли сделать так чтобы после query запроса исполнялся ->free()? Есть ли для этого какие то иные меры

Comment: В класс работы с бд не заглядывали? `$db->("SELECT * FROM `table`")->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` нет такого в стандартном php.

Comment: Простите немного ошибся $db->query()

Comment: переопределите метод fetch_array() и внутри вставьте free(). Например.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение немного не стандартное) крон всегда решает проблемы.
Исполняется раз в 30 секунд:

```
$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 1");
 $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();
 $sql->free();
```

[image: Демонстрация]